# How to use wildcard * in alias

Tags: shell, zsh, alias, quoting

```
# first examle
> alias gostyle="goimports -w $(find . -type f -name '*.go' -not -path './vendor/*')"
> alias gostyle
gostyle=$'goimports -w / gofiles /'

# second example
> alias gostyle="goimports -w $(find . -type f -name 'main.go' -not -path './vendor/*')"
> alias gostyle
gostyle='goimports -w ./main.go'
```

Why in first example I have $ in the front of command.
How I can use wildcard * right in alias.
Why I have permission denied when I use first alias

Comment: The `$'...'` string is just Bash's way to tell you that the string is a "C-style" string. In this case, it is identical to a regular single-quoted string. (I'm guessing you actually replaced the _actual_ output with `/ gofiles /`manually.)

Comment: yes I replaced,  / gofiles / it's files that found by ```find . -type f -name '*.go' -not -path './vendor/*'```

Comment: As an aside, your question cannot be about [tag:bash] and [tag:zsh] at the same time. If you are using Zsh, its syntax differs from standard Bourne shell syntax in pesky ways, also depending on how you configure it.

Comment: Since we're talking about `zsh`, we don't need `find` at all. Something like `goimports -w *.go~./vendor/*(.)` (with the `extended_glob` option set) would suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using double quotes instead of single, the `$(find ...)` is executed once, at the time you define your alias.  You end up with an alias with a hard-coded list of files.

The trivial fix is to use single quotes instead of double (where obviously then you need to change the embedded single quotes to double quotes instead, or come up with a different refactoring); but a much better solution is to use a function instead of an alias. There is basically no good reason to use an alias other than for backwards  compatibility with dot files from the paleolithic age of Unix.

```
gostyle () {
    goimports -w $(find . -type f -name '*.go' -not -path './vendor/*') "$@"
}
```

(Unfortunately, I am not familiar with `goimports`; perhaps it needs its argument to be double quoted, or perhaps you should add one `-w` for each result that `find` produces. Or perhaps you actually want

```
gostyle () {
    find . -type f -name '*.go' -not -path './vendor/*' -print0 |
    xargs -0 goimports -w "$@"
}
```

where you might or might not want to include `"$@"`.)

Comment: Pretty sure Unix does not appear earlier than the Neolithic, if not later :)